# Cannot display "xampp-linux-x64-8.0.2-0-installer.run"

Tags: 20.04, php, xampp

Apparently i can not run the executable cause I need a runner or something. Does anybody know how to run it or install xampp with php 8 from the terminal? :)

https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html

this is where im trying to download/install it from

Comment: Did you first `chmod +x ,/file_name` (from a terminal in the same directory) and then run `sudo ./file_name` in that same terminal in that same directory? I just downloaded the file and did so, and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: ooooh i thought i was just supposed to click on it. Thanks!! it worked

Comment: I figured it would, as it worked for me. I've gone ahead and typed up an answer for you and future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, download the file in question. Let's say you downloaded it to /Downloads.

Open your terminal with CTRL ALT T.

```
cp Downloads
chmod +x ./<file name>
```

Note: You can use tab for autocompletion. So, `./xam<tab>` will likely autocomplete the name for you.

Then, you just run it as a privileged used:

```
sudo ./xam<tab>
```

Press the enter button and a GUI will pop up to help you finish the installation and configuration.